# Change the colour of p-dropdown items based on a Boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, p-dropdown

I want to change the background colour of my primeng drop-down items which is dependent on a boolean value that I'm getting from an api and pushing it into a array i.e users

I have a array of objects users which contains 3 fields.
Response of the api is:

```
users=[{user_name:john.doe,user_id:'J012', is_promoted:true},{user_name:jane.doe,user_id:'J013', is_promoted:false}]
So I was trying to map the users array to get the is_promoted
users.map(u=>u.is_promoted);
```

If is_promoted is true then the background colour of p-dropdown-items must change to a certain colour.I'm not able to achieve this. Should I try [styleClass]?
CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep.p-dropdown-items{
background:darkgrey
}
```

HTML

```
<p-dropdown [options]=users optionlabel="user_name" optionvalue="user_id" 
[ngStyle]="{'highlight':users.is_promoted==true}"[(ngModel)]="selectedValue> //Gives an error
```

I'm able to select the value here. But I need to change the background colour of the dropdown element based on the boolean value. How to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking NgPrime dropdown, right?

You need to use template for this. From the [docs](https://primeng.org/dropdown):

```css
.promoted {
   background-color: red;

}
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-panel .p-dropdown-items .p-dropdown-item {
  padding:0;
}
.userItem {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="users" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" optionLabel="user_name" optionValue="user_id" >
    <ng-template let-user pTemplate="item">
        <div class='userItem' [class.promoted]="user.is_promoted" >{{user.user_name}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

You need also change padding on `.p-dropdown-item` because background will be only around the text, not whole option element.

Comment: This is not working in my scenario. It's not giving any error but the promoted class is not applied to the element

Comment: I could solve this one by tweaking the code a little bit. Thanks